# UDP Multicast traffic being blocked by the wireless router

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, wifi, multicast

I am developing an app that sends Multicast UDP packets to discover devices running the same app in the same local network, using the address 224.0.0.1 and the port 8875. It worked perfectly until a few days ago I replaced my wireless router and found that with the new one I am unable to receive the multicast traffic. Seems like the router is blocking intentionally that traffic, and while I'm sure I can tweak some options to unblock it, obviously I'd like my software to work out of the box on any wireless network.

I haven't been able to find any documentation about what traffic do exactly wireless routes filter by default (I assume there is not a convention and depends on the manufacuturer), so I was hoping someone could give me any guidelines/clues about what traffic is "safe", and what will be probably get blocked.

Comment: Routers block multicasts unless you enable multicast routing. It sounds like you are confusing terms. If everything is on the same network, you aren't using a router. It sounds like you mean the WAP, since you are doing this with Wi-Fi. The router and the WAP are in the same box, probably with a switch, firewall, and DHCP server, too, but you aren't using the router on the same network, since routers route between networks. This question doesn't actually have to do with programming, so it is off-topic here, and you should try to ask it on [su].

Comment: Have you tried to increase the TTL on your multicast socket?

Comment: @RonMaupin Sure, by router I meant the whole device even if I am just operating inside the WAP. I'll try asking there!

Comment: @StianSkjelstad No, why should it matter if my traffic isn't going through any router?

Comment: Your wireless router will be a hop, and if ip stack in it has special support for multicast, ttl points can be shaved off, or cause packet to be discareded even if too low